# Add ACF fields to search results page WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a file named search.php, where all the search results are added.
The search form is located on the homepage. The problem is, I have no special page for the search results, but I want to add ACF fields to this page. I have searched in the dropdown menu 'location' in the ACF plugin, but I can't find the search.php file to add groups to. I am sorry if my explaination is a bit vague, but I don't know how to explain this exactly.

Summary, I want to add ACF fields to my search.php search results page.

Terminology: ACF stand for the Advanced Custom Fields plugin in WordPress.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can also do it using plugin but use below code to avoide plugin.

You need to add this code in you function.php file

```
<?php
/**
 * [list_searcheable_acf list all the custom fields we want to include in our search query]
 * @return [array] [list of custom fields]
 */
function list_searcheable_acf(){
  $list_searcheable_acf = array("title", "sub_title", "excerpt_short", "excerpt_long", "xyz", "myACF");
  return $list_searcheable_acf;
}
/**
 * [advanced_custom_search search that encompasses ACF/advanced custom fields and taxonomies and split expression before request]
 * @param  [query-part/string]      $where    [the initial "where" part of the search query]
 * @param  [object]                 $wp_query []
 * @return [query-part/string]      $where    [the "where" part of the search query as we customized]
 * see https://vzurczak.wordpress.com/2013/06/15/extend-the-default-wordpress-search/
 * credits to Vincent Zurczak for the base query structure/spliting tags section
 */
function advanced_custom_search( $where, &$wp_query ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( empty( $where ))
        return $where;

    // get search expression
    $terms = $wp_query->query_vars[ 's' ];

    // explode search expression to get search terms
    $exploded = explode( ' ', $terms );
    if( $exploded === FALSE || count( $exploded ) == 0 )
        $exploded = array( 0 => $terms );

    // reset search in order to rebuilt it as we whish
    $where = '';

    // get searcheable_acf, a list of advanced custom fields you want to search content in
    $list_searcheable_acf = list_searcheable_acf();
    foreach( $exploded as $tag ) :
        $where .= " 
          AND (
            (wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%$tag%')
            OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%$tag%')
            OR EXISTS (
              SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta
                  WHERE post_id = wp_posts.ID
                    AND (";
        foreach ($list_searcheable_acf as $searcheable_acf) :
          if ($searcheable_acf == $list_searcheable_acf[0]):
            $where .= " (meta_key LIKE '%" . $searcheable_acf . "%' AND meta_value LIKE '%$tag%') ";
          else :
            $where .= " OR (meta_key LIKE '%" . $searcheable_acf . "%' AND meta_value LIKE '%$tag%') ";
          endif;
        endforeach;
            $where .= ")
            )
            OR EXISTS (
              SELECT * FROM wp_comments
              WHERE comment_post_ID = wp_posts.ID
                AND comment_content LIKE '%$tag%'
            )
            OR EXISTS (
              SELECT * FROM wp_terms
              INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy
                ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id
              INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships
                ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
              WHERE (
                taxonomy = 'post_tag'
                    OR taxonomy = 'category'                
                    OR taxonomy = 'myCustomTax'
                )
                AND object_id = wp_posts.ID
                AND wp_terms.name LIKE '%$tag%'
            )
        )";
    endforeach;
    return $where;
}

add_filter( 'posts_search', 'advanced_custom_search', 500, 2 );
```

for reference - https://gist.github.com/charleslouis/5924863

Try This solution if first is not working.

https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/making-customfields-searchable/

Comment: Still working like a charm in 2022

Comment: Using this function return the following warnings for me: Parameter 2 to advanced_custom_search() expected to be a reference, value given in /wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 308. Should I simply remove & in the &$wp_query parameter?

Answer (score 1):

it works for me

```
function custom_search_query( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_search ) {
        $result = $query->query_vars['s'];
        $query->query_vars['s'] = '';
        $query->set('meta_query', array('relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'     => 'acf_name', // ACF FIELD NAME OR POST META
                'value'   => $result,
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            )
        ));
        $query->set('post_type', 'post'); // optional POST TYPE
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_search_query');
```