# Custom WordPress Search

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom post type 'Artist'. I also have individual artist pages for each of my 3 artists. I limited my default wordpress search to search only for 'Artist' post type using this in the functions.php file.

```
   function searchfilter($query) {

    if ($query->is_search && !is_admin() ) {
    $query->set('post_type',array('Artist'));
    }
    return $query;
    }
    add_filter('pre_get_posts','searchfilter');
```

Now, How can I make sure, that if I type the artist name, it shows the search results on the artist page and not on the default search page.

Example, if I type John in the search box, the search results should show the all the content of the Artist page which contains the word John.

Here is the search.php code

```
      <?php
    if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php 
        /* Start the Loop */
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            /**
             * Run the loop for the search to output the results.
             * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
             * called content-search.php and that will be used instead.
             */
            <?php the_title(); ?>
            <?php the_content(); ?>

        endwhile;

        the_posts_navigation();

    else :


        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

    endif; ?>
```

Comment: The search results will show all the `artist` pages that have the keywords and not just one artist page. Do you want to show only one page? What do you want to happen if users search for keywords that are in both artist pages?

Comment: Hi Amit,

So, If I type John, it should show me all the divs on all the pages that contain the word John. If the word john is on both the pages, it should show all the divs of both the pages that contain the word John. Right now I am getting the titles of all the pages that contain the word John

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add ACF fields to search results page WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36787391/add-acf-fields-to-search-results-page-wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

OK so you want to show the contents of the searched posts as well.
Querying the posts and showing the results are 2 different things. All the code you wrote here does is to modify the `query` so that only posts of type `Artist` are shown. To show the result you must have run the loop on the search results somewhere. Add a line to show the contents there (search for `the_content` or `get_the_content`).

Comment: Please refer to the added code above. It is still showing just the title and not the content. The content I am trying to show is built using ACF. But it aint showing up on search results.

Comment: You are giving all the info in such a piecemeal :). If the content is coming from the ACF, then the you need to get the fields from the acf contents. Search for `get_field` and `the_field` now or get the info from https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

Comment: and how could I Do that ? I have a custom field "description". If it contains the word John how can I display it on search results page ?

Comment: Assuming `description` is the id of your custom field, `the_field('description')` after `the_content();` should do the trick.

Comment: You mean like this

<div class="entry-summary">
    
   <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php the_field('description');?>
    
 </div>

Comment: well yes. Give it a try.

Comment: Did that mate. Same result. Just the title and link of all the pages containing the word "John"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150985/discussion-between-amit-joshi-and-jon-snow).