# Post content is not displaying ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Why can't I see the post content where as I can easily see the post title if I do a wordpress search. I have a custom post type "Artist" and I am using ACF.

```
            <?php
            if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php
             /* Start the Loop */
             while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>






           <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
           <header class="entry-header">
           <?php the_title( sprintf( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h2>' ); ?>

              </header><!-- .entry-header -->

             <div class="entry-summary">
             <?php the_content(); ?>
              </div><!-- .entry-summary -->

             <footer class="entry-footer">
             <?php edigital_entry_footer(); ?>
             </footer><!-- .entry-footer -->
             </article><!-- #post-## -->
```

Comment: Please clarify your question... the_content is not part of acf. In fact there are no acf functions in the code provided.

Comment: I am using ACF and I have a custom post type "team". I have disabled all the post types from search results except "team". Now when I am performing a search for say "John". It is only displaying the title and permalink.
I can't seem to be able to display the content under "John"

Comment: If the code you posted above is the search result page, then you need to follow @CKG example below and wrap your code in the wp loop.

Comment: I updated the above code. It still is showing just the title and permalinks

Comment: Hi @user3678230 Where do you do "I have disabled all the post types from search results except "team""? Sorry but I can't understand the problematic.

Comment: `                  
function searchfilter($query) {

if ($query->is_search && !is_admin() ) {
$query->set('post_type',array('Artist'));
}
return $query;

}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','searchfilter');
          `

Comment: Hi Jose, I just added the above code in the functions.php file. now it will only display the 'artist' post type.

Comment: But still, I can't display the content

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add ACF fields to search results page WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36787391/add-acf-fields-to-search-results-page-wordpress)

Answer (score 1):

You need to put **"the content"** function call inside the WordPress loop in order for it to output your content to the page like the following.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Hope that helps, Cheers!!!